# Firefox: Hovering over button with dropdown immediately hides the dropdown when moving the mouse over to it

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a fairly typical dropdown markup with the main difference being the container is a button instead of a div, which is what seems to be the main cause of the issue in Firefox. The button contains a list inside it and when I hover over the button the list displays fine. But when I start to move to the dropdown list, the hover on the button deactivates. If I use a DIV element instead of a BUTTON, then it works fine in both browsers. Here's the code I'm using (plnkr: [plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/edit/cxIDVHlx2WMSWI5MZrbv))

```
<!--Using 'button': does not work in Firefox-->
<button class="button">
   button text: this doesn't work in Firefox but works in Chrome
   <ul>
       <li>Item 1</li>
       <li>Item 2</li>
       ...
   </ul>
</button>

<!--Switching to 'div': works fine-->
<div class="button">
   switching to DIV: this works as expected
   <ul>
       <li>Item 1</li>
       <li>Item 2</li>
       ...
   </ul>
</div>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
.button {
  position: relative;
}

.button > ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}

.button:hover > ul {
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

It would be great if someone can help me figure out why this behavior is differs in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: `button`s are not really allowed to have children in Firefox.

Comment: I have the exact same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend a ul inside a button. So you could do two things to achieve your goal.

1 - List after the button:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<button class="button">Button</button>
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
<!-- CSS -->
button+ul {
    display: none;
}
button:hover+ul {
    display: block;
}
```

This works ([**check demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/ab4km/)), however you won't be able to hover on the ul (which you probably want).

2 - Wrap it inside a div

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="buttonClass">
    <button>Button</button>
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- CSS -->
.buttonClass>ul {
    display: none;
}
.buttonClass:hover>ul {
    display: block;
}
```

This way ([**check demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/ab4km/1/)), you can hover the ul

Comment: Yes, I'm aware I could just use a div to accomplish the same task and my current implementation is actually similar to your 2nd example. My question was about the difference between the behaviors in Chrome and Firefox, where Chrome has no problem with the dropdown, while Firefox deactivates hover state when you move over to the list.